# adding navigation bar to detailview and tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

i am developing an iPhone app in which there is a uitableview and a when any of the rows in the table view is selected, a new viewcontroller will be loaded which shows details about the selected row in the tableview . My problem is that i need a navigation bar in the tableview and the details view,the navigation bar should have back button ie the navigation bar on detail view should have a back button to tableview should have a back button to earlier view controller.How can i do this programatically??

Comment: It seems that you are very new to iOS development. So better go for this tutorial http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/ . B4 u post your questions please search for tutorials on it. Ask questions where u r getting errors or stuff like that.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder i have tried may tutorials but the does seem to help that why i asked it here.sorry for the trouble

Comment: hey buddy no need to be sorry we all are here to help each other. Why I suggest you so coz your simple question may get 'down vote' which will reflect to your stack overflow reputation. . So b4 u ask just check for tutorials. BTW if my link has helped you then please vote my comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

The viewcontroller with the tableview should be the root view controller of a navigation controller (which you can create programatically). Then you just push (pushviewcontroller:animated:) the detail view controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
     NSLog(@"self.topItem.title = %@", self.topItem.title);
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"];
     [image drawInRect:frame];
     UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
     [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 20.0];
     //label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1];
     label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
     label.textColor = RGBCOLOR(73, 81, 85);
     label.text = self.topItem.title;
     self.topItem.titleView = label;
    self.tintColor = RGBCOLOR(229, 239, 246);
  }
 @end
```

also add UIButton and it's Action event to Navigate between View Controlllers